# How to sign a PowerShell script easily?

Tags: windows, security, powershell, script, code-signing

I'd prefer using the AllSigned execution policy with PowerShell, but self-signing my scripts seems to require several hundreds of megabytes of downloading and installation and the signing process seems to be a hassle.

Is there a simpler way to sign a PowerShell script than described in the documentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do the signing you can use the `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` cmdlet. This, of course, requires a certificate. If you have a Certificate Authority (unlikely) that will be able to create a code signing certificate. Otherwise there are various tools to create a self-signed certificate.

You install the certificate in your certificate store (open the `.cer` or `.pfx` file in Windows Explorer to do this), and then pass it to `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` (the `cert:` provider/drive gives access to certificates in your store).

Use

```
help about_signing
```

or the [online version](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_signing) of that help topic for details (including creating a self-signed certificate using the Windows SDK tools<sup>[1]</sup>).

<sup>[1]</sup> I assume this is the big download you're referring to: you can just install the bits you need, or make use of other tools (OpenSSL includes certificate generation). Getting the SDK is, for this purpose, a one-off activity.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer and assuming that there is no shortcut and signing just needs to be done as mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Like quite a few "developer-y" things the initial set up and learning is hard, but the actual practice (especially if done regularly) isn't.

Comment: For anyone who needs to make a self signed cert to do the above I found these two links helpful: https://serverfault.com/questions/824574/create-code-signing-certificate-on-windows-for-signing-powershell-scripts and https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4753

Answer (score 6):

I use this PowerShell script:

```
## sign-script.ps1
## Sign a powershell script with a Thawte certificate and 
## timestamp the signature
##
## usage: ./sign-script.ps1 c:\foo.ps1 

param([string] $file=$(throw “Please specify a script filepath.”)) 

$certFriendlyName = "Thawte Code Signing"
$cert = gci cert:\CurrentUser\My -codesigning | where -Filter 
  {$_.FriendlyName -eq $certFriendlyName}

# https://www.thawte.com/ssl-digital-certificates/technical-  
#   support/code/msauth.html#timestampau
# We thank VeriSign for allowing public use of their timestamping server.
# Add the following to the signcode command line: 
# -t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll 
$timeStampURL = "http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll"

if($cert) {
    Set-AuthenticodeSignature -filepath $file -cert $cert -IncludeChain All -   
      TimeStampServer $timeStampURL
}
else {
    throw "Did not find certificate with friendly name of `"$certFriendlyName`""
}
```

Comment: How can you use a script to sign a script? Wouldn't your script signing script need to be signed?

Answer (score 6):

Once I had the certificate, I wanted to use imported on my user account. This regkey gave me an option, *Sign*, in the context menu (I'm using Windows 7). If the certificate you want to sign with is stored differently, just change the [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) command at the end.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Sign]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Sign\Command]
@="C:\\\Windows\\\System32\\\WindowsPowerShell\\\v1.0\\\powershell.exe -command Set-AuthenticodeSignature '%1' @(Get-ChildItem cert:\\\CurrentUser\\\My -codesigning)[0]"
```

Comment: This worked for me for years until I changed the default app for .ps1 files from "Notepad" to "Visual Studio Code".  After I made that change, I lost the "Sign" option in the Explorer context menu.  Switching the default app back to "Notepad" restored the "Sign" option in the explorer context menu.

Comment: This trick also works for Powershell **module** files by creating the same set of keys as in the answer but substituting `Microsoft.PowerShellModule.1` for `Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1`.